# How to read each char sent by Putty at Java server?

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, putty, serversocket

After forcing off the "Local line editing" at Putty (Raw mode), all chars typed are sent to the server without the Enter (checked it with Wireshark).

I have this code:

```
ServerSocket listener = null;
BufferedReader is;
listener = new ServerSocket(22);
socket = listener.accept();

is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()););
while (true) {
    line = is.readLine();
    os.write("Shell#");
    os.flush(); 
}
```

This code need an Enter from Putty to read all the sequence chars typed,

How to read these sent chars one by one at Java Server side ?

Comment: If you don't want to wait for a line terminate why are you using `readLine()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have discovered, `readLine()` reads **whole** lines, thus won't return before a newline marks the **end** of a line.

Also note that the whole point of a `BufferedReader` is to **buffer** data.

The real answer here is to carefully look at the different classes your code is using. Meaning: check out [read()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#read()) in the InputStreamReader class!